# React-Native Add Mob error Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative. View.propTypes.style')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I installed the npm add mob and linked it with react-native.
Also got my unit id and menifest-xml id.

How to fix en error  when I import `{ AdMobBanner }` from `react-native-admob`:

> "Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.
>   View.propTypes.style')"

Comment: crazy this Admob sucks